# Django: InlineAdmin and ManyToManyField with 'through'

Tags: django, django-admin, manytomanyfield

I'm having a simple `Gallery` model, that is related to an `Image` model via a many-to-many relationship through a table that has an `ordering`-attribute:

```
# models.py
class Image(models.Model):
    ....

class Gallery(models.Model):
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image, through='ImageGallery')
    ....

class ImageGallery(models.Model)
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image)
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery)
    ordering = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('ordering'), default=0)

# admin.py
class ImageGalleryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = ImageGallery

class GalleryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (ImageGalleryAdmin,)
```

I'm editing the 'through' table via an inline admin.

What I'd like to do is to be able to upload/edit the images directly in the inline admin, so I'd like to know if anybody knows an exisiting snippet, that allows me to edit the field of the 'through'-table together with the fields of the referenced model (the image), not needing to edit the foreign key select....

Comment: i'd like the same thing... Just to clarify the question somewhat, using standard django inlines, attributes of the final model aren't available – only attributes of the 'through' model (e.g. the order parameter) can be edited in the inline. I think what is desired is that both the order parameter and parameters of the linked object are editable in the same inline.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this question has already been answered here:

[Django admin - inline inlines (or, three model editing at once)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702637/django-admin-inline-inlines-or-three-model-editing-at-once)

You need to create a custom form and template for the inline which references the linked object.

Answer (score -1):

I might not have understood your question. Can't you just use:

> class ImageAdmin (admin.ModelAdmin)
>
> ```
> inlines = (ImageGalleryAdmin,)
> ```
>
> admin.site.register(Image, ImageAdmin)