# Django admin inline popups

Tags: python, django, django-admin, inline-formset

Like a many other users here i have been thwarted in trying to get nested inline forms working in the django admin.

I have a data structure that is roughly

Group
 - Some data fields

Patrol
 - Foreign key to groups
 - Some different data fields

Scout
 - Foreign key to patrol
 - Even more data fields

Ideally when i go to edit a `Group` record, i would have the admin interface present the `Patrol` instances linked to scout shown though `StackedInline` and then have the `Scout` records related to each of these patrols show up inside an inner `TabularInline` however this is not currently possible, i have spent a large amount of time trying to port over [a patch from two years ago](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9025) but have had little success.

As far as i see it i have three options open to me

1. Persist with trying to get this patch from an age ago to work
2. List patrol objects within a `TabularInline` without the scout relation and provide an edit patrol members link that pops up a form to edit a patrol in a new window.
3. Just keep it simple and make users of the system go back and forth between editing group and patrols

Option 2 is what currently looks the most promising but i need advice as to how i could pop up an extra window to edit the patrol in.

Any advice on how to do this, how to get nested inline fields to work or another way in general would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you can try something like the following:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702637/django-admin-inline-inlines-or-three-model-editing-at-once

Comment: Yea I didn't really get how I would impilement that how do I plug that form into the current system, do I specify it in tabular inline?