# Model Relationships in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model that contains 3 class (Person, Business, Renewal)
Relation: A Person can have multiple Business and each business can have multiple Renewal.
Problem: For the admin.py I would use inline to connect Person(modelAdmin) with Business(StackedInline). Now my problem is how to connect renewal with business.

basically the there is a 2nd layer of relationship.

Comment: is this what you need? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702637/django-admin-inline-inlines-or-three-model-editing-at-once

Comment: @doniyor yes similar problem, the only thing is I want to do it on the admin.py how do i do the nested relationships in admin.py

Comment: I never tried it, but this seems to address your issue: https://github.com/s-block/django-nested-inline/

Comment: @mbrochh i tried that unfortunately they won't work with django 1.7 due to some depreciation, unless you know a work around.