# How to add foreign key relationships from within django admin

Tags: django, django-models

I two model classes

```
class Product(models.Model)
    name = ...

class Part(models.Model)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete= models.CASCADE,default=1)
```

In my database I already have populated a number of parts.

Is there a way to change Admin to allow a drop down/select of parts for the product I'm looking at,

e.g I want to assign a foreign key relationship of parts A, B, C, F to the Product I'm looking at the admin page for Proudct X.

I have seen the [inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702637/django-admin-inline-inlines-or-three-model-editing-at-once) option, but I don't want to add new parts, I just want to be able to associate the parts with the product I'm looking at

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Althoug not an answer, why do you set `default=1` in the `ForeignKey`?

Comment: Oh, I kinda paired down the class for brevity of example. Honestly, it was just a remnant of when I built the models initially. I think I had it because i added the field later, and django did that thing where when running manage.py migrate it said "set a default" to continue, so I just added one, and the I made the Product 1 a "test product"